# MVC Caching for all users vs local cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is the following possible:

- Cache list to be available for all users
- If one item of the list is modified then re-Cache the list

Other scenario

- Cache list in user browser
- If on item of the list is modified, refresh all other users versions

I'm very confused with all the built in cache objects available in .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, without seeing your code it's hard to fully verify if I'm on the right track here but...

**Re: Cache for all users:**

You could use `OutputCache` on an/the action that returns your list.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=3600, VaryByParam="refreshCache", Location=OutputCacheLocation.Server, NoStore=true)]
public ActionResult GetTheList(bool refreshCache=false)
{
    return Content("")
}
```

`OutputCacheLocation.Server` means the cache would be stored on the server...this can also be set to `Client` (**cache in browser**).

`VaryByParam="refreshCache"` if you pass `refreshCache=true` it will refresh the list on the server.

`Duration` the amount of seconds the item will be cached for.

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding the requirements...if so, please post some code examples of what you have so far...

More info on OutputCache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs